# IE8-Compatibility: why is a specific <p> screwed up?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser, ie8-compatibility-mode, ie-developer-tools

I have a wonderful website and unfortunately there is ONE (yeah, ONLY one!) problem left related to compatibility: pls. check yourself - http://podologen-symposium.de/podologen-symposium/anmeldung/ displayes fine. I'm also attaching a screenshot which shows what I was expecting to see and what I saw:[image]

I've used IE9 with Developer-Tools enabled and viewed that page in all modes (IE7, IE8 and IE9) and it also displayed correctly. Only my client, who used IE8, complained - because one paragraph is shown at the wrong place. I have no idea why - any ideas anyone? 
[image]
Thanks

Michael

Comment: it should be shown across the two buttons at the bottom of the page.
The HTML-Code for it is:

<div class="labelobj" id="label26">
<p><span style="font-size: 8pt;"><em><span style="font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif;">Bitte füllen Sie die mit * gekennzeichneten Felder unbedingt aus</span></em></span></p>
</div>

Comment: I can't reproduce, I tried with chrome 23.0.1271.95, firefox 12.0, internet explorer 8.0.7600.16385 and all look the same, the paragraph is also displaying correctly in IE 8 here...

Comment: one thing I noticed is that you are positioning every element with `position: absolute`, this is a bad pratice

Comment: Hmm, thanks José - it's helpful to know that there is at least one instance where IE8 renders this correctly :)  That form, btw, is being created from a TYPO3-Component, so I have only very limited influence on it...